# Track Network Usage in Wifi Connection

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I'm a student staying at a communal residence of 6 people and the rent includes internet access which is supposedly uncapped but if you really push your downloads(lets say more than 300GB) the ISP cancels your connection for the rest of the month. I have to do a lot online tutorial for my course so I can't afford to be a week without internet ... So here is my question is there a program that I can easily use to see how much traffic each person is using(I don't want to see what anyone is searching or violate their privacy. I just want know how much data each house mate is using so i can tell them to easy it down a bit.)I don't have the admin password for the router and i am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Thank You.

Comment: Is this a wireless router? Chances are, with wired you can't - in the old days, with a "hub", every computer could see every packet - nowadays almost everything is a "switch" & you can't - wireless is easier as you can see the packets again. They should be encrypted so a count of packets is a guide. Not accurate. `sudo etherape` is fun to watch & may inform you a little.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using this program [Traffic monitor applet for GNOME](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/netspeed/)

The only easy solutions is that each player has installed this applet, and have a look every week.

There'are professional solutions as a netflow analizers for accounting all of your traffic, but isn't easy solution. In all of cases you will need a server, and I think isn't a communal residence solution.